# How to delete from 3 tables with one query using where exists

Tags: sql, database, oracle, spring-boot

I have four tables Monitoring, Participant, Participant validation group, Validation group,

I would like to delete all monitorings, and there particpants also each particpant possibly (not always) has participant validation group.

> Blockquote

but i have the error sql command not properly ended.
NOTE: I am on oracle database and inner joins would not work here.

**I would like to achieve an optimized query
that could take only the application number of monitoring and delete all monitorings, participants for each monitoring and participant validation group.**

I am not sure if its actually possible in a single query if its not then what could be the optimized way to do this. and I cant use jpa for this at the moment.

**Expected results, both monitorings are deleted, and there particpants as well as participant validation groups**

Comment: Whenever you have a question, please post a little sample data (CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for all tables involved, relevant columns only) so the people who want to help you can recreate the problem and test their ideas. Also post the exact results you want from that data, and explain why you want those results from that data. Lastly, don't post any images as they cant be cut and pasted.

Comment: Please, minimize you sample model: keep only columns used in filters/relationships and remove physical properties of the table (it doesn't necesary to specify what is the table space and initial extent for your exact issue)

Answer (score 1):

You can define foreign keys on child tables to "ON DELETE CASCADE". So when you delete a parent table it will delete associated rows from child tables.

```
create table parent (
  id NUMBER(10),
  value      varchar2(30),
constraint parent_pk primary key (id)
);

CREATE TABLE child
( id NUMBER(10) not null,
value NUMBER(10) not null,
constraint child_pk primary key (id,value),
CONSTRAINT parent_child_fk
FOREIGN KEY (id)
REFERENCES parent(id)
ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE grandchild
( id NUMBER(10) not null,
value NUMBER(10) not null,
constraint grandchild_pk primary key (id,value),
CONSTRAINT child_grandchild_fk
FOREIGN KEY (id,value)
REFERENCES child(id,value)
ON DELETE CASCADE
);


insert into parent values (1,'a');
insert into parent values (2,'b');
insert into parent values (3,'c');

insert into child  values (1,1);
insert into child  values (1,2);
insert into child  values (1,3);
insert into child  values (2,1);
insert into child  values (2,2);
insert into child  values (2,3);
insert into child  values (3,1);
insert into child  values (3,2);
insert into child  values (3,3);

insert into grandchild  values (1,1);
insert into grandchild  values (1,2);
insert into grandchild  values (1,3);
insert into grandchild  values (2,1);
insert into grandchild  values (2,2);
insert into grandchild  values (2,3);
insert into grandchild  values (3,1);
insert into grandchild  values (3,2);
insert into grandchild  values (3,3);

SELECT  (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM   parent 
        ) AS parent_cnt,
       (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM   child 
        ) AS child_cnt,
        (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM   grandchild
        ) AS grandchild_cnt
FROM    dual

DELETE from parent where value = 'a';

SELECT  (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM   parent 
        ) AS parent_cnt,
       (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM   child 
        ) AS child_cnt,
        (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM   grandchild
        ) AS grandchild_cnt
FROM    dual

PARENT_CNT    CHILD_CNT    GRANDCHILD_CNT
2    6    6
```

Comment: i have posted the DDL we already have cascade delete on them, but i want to achieve deletion by a query that could be delete from monitoring, participant, pvg ....

Comment: I dont see on DELETt E CASCADE clause on the ddl you posted.

Comment: @valik `DELETE` does not support multiple tables. You must use `CASCADE` or execute multiple `DELETE` statements. See the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/DELETE.html#GUID-156845A5-B626-412B-9F95-8869B988ABD7

Comment: Did my post answer your question